# Using Squeeze Theorem, find limit $(5^{n} + 6^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find limit of $(a_{n}) = (5^{n} + 6^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ given $b^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1, b \in R^{+}$

Is it too cheeky to say let $b = (5^{n} + 6^{n})$ and say by definition $(5^{n} + 6^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$?

Comment: Do you **really** believe that $\lim_{n\to\infty}5^n+6^n=1$?

Comment: what is $b$ ? Please be precise, what you wrote doesn't make sense ? And $(5^n+6^n)\to 1$ is wrong as well !

Comment: $$6^n<5^n+6^n<2\cdot6^n$$

Comment: Something seems to be amiss!?

Comment: that really is the question. I think lab has cracked it, thanks lab

Comment: I wouldn't say cheecky. I'd say plain wrong.

Comment: explain how so @YvesDaoust

Comment: @number8: care to read my answer. The limit is $6$.

Comment: The question itself is fine. But  your distraction with $b$  is not correct the thing is $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty} b^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ is true as long as $b$ is not a function of $n$ (that too  an exponentially increasing!).. Your setting $b=5^n+6^n$ is not cheeky but it is wrong. If one sets $b=7^n$ then the asymptotic limit is 7  and not 1. The question is fine but without $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, we have $6^n\leq5^n+6^n\leq2\cdot6^n$ so the desired limit is inbetween $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(6^n\right)^{1/n}=6$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2\cdot6^n\right)^{1/n}=6\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{1/n}=6\cdot1=6$. Both limits equal $6$ so the final answer is $6$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

$(5^n+6^n)^{1\over n}=e^{{ln(5^n+6^n)}\over n}$

$=e^{{{nln(6)}\over n}+{ln(1+({5\over 6})^n)\over n})}$ so the limit is $6$

Comment: This doesn't use the Squeeze Theorem...

Comment: In fact, it doesn't answer anything, there is no justification for the final result.